# Nested interval property and density of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

My lecturer asks us to prove this: $$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)=\emptyset$$ But it seems I can find a way to prove this is not true. According to the density of rational numbers in real numbers , there exists a rational in interval $(a,b)$ . So no matter how small an interval is , we can find a number. So it is not empty. Can anyone guide me on this ? I'm very confusing now.

Comment: If you wish to prove that the set is non-empty, you need to find a *single* number, $a$, that is in *every* interval $(0,1/n)$. Just finding possibly different numbers (rational or not) in  these intervals does not accomplish this.

Comment: I see. So can I reasoning like this: By the density of rational numbers in real number , there exists a rational number in an interval. But there exists an even smaller interval which does not contain the rational number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The density of the rationals means that we can always find a rational $x_{a,b}\in (a,b)$. The thing to note here is that $x_{a,b}$ depends on $a,b$!.
More rigorously:
$$\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}:a<b\ \exists x\in \mathbb{Q}: x\in (a,b)$$
This is not the same as
$$\exists x\in \mathbb{Q}\ \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}:a<b\ x\in (a,b)$$
which you are implying. If we try to apply the density of rationals in this case we have that:
$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\ \exists x_n\in \mathbb{Q}: x_n\in (0,\frac 1n)$$
This doesn't mean however that
$$x_n\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(0,\frac 1n)$$
as $x_n$ only needs to be a member of each own $(0,\frac 1n)$ and not for the smaller intervals.

Instead our only hope would be for this to hold for the limit. But there is a problem, the limit is $0$! Indeed as $0<x_n<\frac 1n$ $x_n$ converges and to $0$. But obviously,
$$0\notin \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(0,\frac 1n)$$
and so our argument collapses. In fact,
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(0,\frac 1n)=\emptyset$$
because if it weren't then,
$$\exists x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(0,\frac 1n)\iff 0<x<\frac 1n\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\iff n<\frac 1x\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$
which is impossible (Archimedean Property of $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: so it is like an infinite loop ? I have a rational number in an interval $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ but I can find smaller interval which does not contain this rational number.

Comment: @Idonknow Pretty much. If you have intervals of the form $[0,\frac 1n)$ then such a rational number would exist ($0$)

Comment: In your explanation, you talk about limit is $0$. But isnt't this mean that the sequence aproaches 0 but not equal to $0$ ? Then we can find a rational number in the interval such that it lies in the intersection ?

Comment: @Idonknow The sequence certainly "aproaches" $0$ (the limit is $0$) and is never equal to $0$ ($x_n\in (0,\frac 1n)\implies x_n>0$). If the intersection were finite such a rational would exist. But because the intersection is (countably) infinite, there is only hope for the limit to be there

Comment: Actually what is $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{(0,\frac{1}{n}})$ ? What is the resulting set ?

Comment: @Idonknow The resulting set is the empty set $\emptyset$. $$\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac 1n)=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}: x\in (0,\frac 1n)\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

Comment: Then can I say like this? I find an element in an interval (a,b) , and then I expand this interval. Can I say that this is the intersection element?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the intersection of all these intervals is nonempty. Now let $x$ belong to the intersection. It follows that $x$ is less than $1/n$ for all integers n and greater than $0$. This contradicts the Archemidean property of the real numbers.